# How does Java compiler handle statically resolvable calls to non-static methods?

Tags: jvm

Do java compilers (javac or eclipse) try to compile method calls as static when the target method is known statically (even if it's not a static method). Eg.

```
class A { 
    void foo() { doStuff(); }
}
...
A a = new A();
a.foo(); // is this compiled as virtual call or static call?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my response at [How to find out what optimizations the JVM applied to my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669071/how-to-find-out-what-optimizations-the-jvm-applied-to-my-code/3669222#3669222)

Comment: Thanks! From this i understand that compiler can create a static call even when it only hopes that it will be static, and JIT patches up things when compiler's dreams didn't come true.

Comment: Note that source code compilers typically generate quite straightforward, not really optimized bytecode, to help JIT compilers do a better job. The optimizations are usually JVM-dependent, not compiler-dependent.